# Efficient way to zip a list with lists nested in another list in python

Tags: python, list, zip

if we want to zip a list with lists nested a another list e.g.

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']  ]
result = [ (1,'a', '1'), (2,'b','2'), (3,'c','3') ]
```

how can it be done efficiently giving the sizes of the lists can be huge? (i.e. we don't want to do b.append(c) beforehand then zip). thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*` operator (See [Python tutorial - Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists))

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']  ]
>>> zip(a, *b)
[(1, 'a', '1'), (2, 'b', '2'), (3, 'c', '3')]
```